# How to force sqlite3 insert random byte arrays?

Tags: python, sqlite, arrays, blob

I want to write vectors of arbitrary ints into an sqlite3 db. Here's a sample of what I do :

```
packed = struct.pack("ii", [7739119, 962812])
print packed # prints '\xef\x16v\x00\xfc\xb0\x0e\x00'
c.execute("INSERT INTO vecs(content) VALUES(?)", [packed])
```

Here, sqlite3 complains :

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that
can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str).
It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
```

The `vecs` column is a `BLOB`. Why is it complaining ? I know my packed string is not a valid utf-8 string, but I don't care about it, I want to store raw bytes. How can I do it ?